# Does there exist a p-group of order 99?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> Does there exist a p-group of order $99$?

We can first observe that $99=3^2 \times 11$. I then believe we need to apply Sylow's theorem but I am not sure how, exactly.

How can I prove existence using Sylow's theorem?

Comment: What is your definition of a $p$-group?

Comment: "Can I use Sylow theorem to prove that there exists a group with order the power of a prime which does not have a power of a prime as its order?" I hope you cannot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A $p$-group has order $p^n$ for some $n$ by definition. Since $99$ has two prime factors, this is impossible.

Comment: Not by the definition that generalizes to infinite groups, which requires all elements to have order a power of $p$. With this definition one needs to invoke for example Cauchy's theorem to get that the definitions agree for finite groups.

Answer (score 6):

You don't need Sylow's theorems:

- By definition, $p$-group is a group such every element has order a power of $p$.
- By Cauchy's theorem, a group of order $99$ has an element of order $3$ and an element of order $11$.

Therefore, a group of order $99$ cannot be a $p$-group because $3$ and $11$ are not powers of the same prime $p$.